# Copy a Tree without parent reference

Tags: java

I want to create a recursive method which can copy a tree and return it as a Tree not a Node. This is the structure:

```
public class Tree {
Node root;

public Tree(Node root) 
    this.root = root;
}

public static class Node {
    int key;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node(int key, Node left, Node right) {
        this.key = key;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Tree copy() {
    if(root == null)
        return new Tree(null);
    else {
        return new Tree(copyRec(root));
    }
}

private Node copyRec(Node node) {
    if(node != null) {
        Node curr = new Node(node.key, null, null);
        curr.left = copyRec(node.left);
        curr.right = copyRec(node.right);
        return curr;
    }
    return null;
}
```